# Добавление категории wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

у меня стоит WPUF и в select стоит значение child of и выбранная мной категория, нужно что бы при публикации кастомной записи, если стоит дочерняя категория ей добавлялась и родительская, помогите пожалуйста